# Redux action types as `new String()` objects

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

in `Redux` actions, one needs to create a lot of action types. Many actions may focused on one subject so one may want to keep naming convention using subject based prefix like `RECEIVE_SUBJECT_RELATIVES`. It means a lot of long strings.

I have an idea to make it easier:

```
subjectActions = {relatives: new String("RELATIVES), children: new String("CHILDREN")}    
anotherSubjectActions = {relatives: new String("RELATIVES), children: new String("CHILDREN")}
```

and then in `reducer` one may write:

```
switch (action.type) {    
    case (subjectActions.relatives)    
    case (anotherSubjectActions.relatives)
```

it is possible because `subjectActions.relatives` === `anotherSubjectActions.relatives`

Question: does it make sense? Does it have any major pitfalls?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know redux but I don't understand why why use `new String` here?

Comment: "*it is possible because `subjectActions.relatives` === `anotherSubjectActions.relatives`*" in Redux? Becayse this is certainly not going to be the case in JS `new String("foo") === new String("foo")` is always going to be false.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, but there are existing libraries like redux-toolkit that provider wrappers over reducers and actions

Comment: Also, your strings are invalid.

Comment: I want to use `new String` because I want to compare `objects` not `string values`.

Comment: @JacekWojcik No, you don't want to compare string objects! If you really wanted objects, you wouldn't use string objects, and they wouldn't compare as equal in that `switch`.

Comment: If you wanted distinct unique comparable values, then you'd use symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you *should* be comparing string types here, not treating them as objects.  Not sure why you'd want to treat them as objects in the first place.

Second, you should specifically use [our new official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org).  In particular, the [`createSlice` API](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice) eliminates the need to write action types or action creators by hand.

Comment: const aaa = "xyz"
const bbb = "xyz"

console.log(aaa === bbb) // returns true


const AAA = new String("xyz")
const BBB = new String("xyz")

console.log(AAA === BBB) // returns false

Comment: Hmm. That is actually surprising to me, but TIL.  Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: The reason is that instead of: `export const RECEIVE_SELECTED_PERSON_SPECIES = "RECEIVE_SELECTED_PERSON_SPECIES";` I want to `export const SELECTED_PERSON = {
  RECEIVE_SPECIES: new String("RECEIVE_SPECIES"),
}` I need `new String` because then in `reducer` I will compare not string values but object references which is safer (if we have really a lot of actions we are likely to have more then one action with the given name- or we have to use really long strings to keep them unique)

Comment: Comparing object references is _not_ "safer".  Please use the `createSlice` API from Redux Toolkit that I linked, which solves your points of concern _and_ will simplify the code you're writing.